# Preventing incorrect macro expansion in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way to prevent gcc from expanding a macro in this:

```
#define putc(a) fputc(a)

...

void _putc(char ch) {}
struct foo { void *(putc)(char ch); }
struct foo f = {_putc;}

(&f)->putc('X'); // this is an error because it gets expanded into fputc, which is very inappropriate.
```

I don't want to use `#undef putc` because it messes up other things.

Comment: That's a horrible macro (`fputc` takes two arguments not one). Simple workaround: don't create variables named like standard functions. And don't define macros named like standard functions either.

Comment: Perhaps, you might be using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: putc is defined as macro in avr-libc so I have no control over it. I want to use putc as a member name in a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including `<stdio.h>` may or may not define macro functions. In either case, a real function is provided.

It's probably not the best idea to name a function pointer like a standard library function, but you *can* do it. To prevent macro expansion, you have basically three options:

- `#undef` it. You said this would mess up other things, though this shouldn't be a problem -- a real function with that name still exists. For some functions, you may miss optimizations or warnings (for functions like `printf`, for example), however (depending on your compiler).
- Don't include the header file and declare the function yourself. I mention this for sake of completeness rather than as a real suggestion. This doesn't work if you need a type definition provided only in the header you don't want to include.
- Don't put an opening parenthesis after the macro name, as in

  ```
  ((&f)->putc)('X'); // or (f.putc)('X'); -- looking less confusing.
  ```